# Power supply design: DC-OK signal relay

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I am designing a power supply but I do not understand the reason for DC-OK inputs. Why do we use them, and how can I implement them in my design?

Comment: if you do not know the reason for a feature, then why do you want to implement it?

Comment: I need to understand then ı will add this feature to my design of course.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The DC-OK signal is often a name given to a signal path not a signal in itself, it's a open contact style of thing, with two pins which either shorted (when things are good) or an open when things are bad. But the whys and hows depend a lot on the rest of the system.

Comment: Schematic needed. Many things could be called DC-OK.

Comment: The 'DC-OK' output signal is a feature of a regulated power supply that's used in a redundant system. It's output via a 'NO' relay contact that closes when the voltage reaches 90% of the set voltage, opens when the voltage drops more than 10% below the set voltage and closes again when the output voltage exceeds 90% of the set voltage. Short bursts are extended to a signal length ranging between 100 and 250 ms. Drops that are shorter than 1 ms are ignored. The signal is independent of whether or not an external voltage is fed into the system from a parallel power supply.

Answer (score 2):

*This answer is posted with an assumption of that the OP mean "Output OK" with "DC_OK".*

---

DC_OK is an **output** generated by the power supply once the output voltage reaches its threshold (usually 90%) and stays within the predefined range (usually between 90% and OVP-overvoltage limit). This applies to multiple-output PSUs as well i.e. the requirements/conditions may need to be met for every single output (e.g. ATX PSUs).

From customer application point of view, DC_OK *(or sometimes referred to as POWER_OK which might be a combination of DC_OK and AC_OK)* is needed for reliable operation. The customer may want to use it as a trigger for some modules or events. For example, your PC can't turn on if there's no PWR_OK signal coming from the ATX PSU.

It's also useful for fault tracking. Some PSUs are able to communicate over some protocols such as PMBus, so a host can log some information with time-stamps periodically, to use during investigation in case of a failure.

There are a couple of ways to generate a DC_OK signal. Following are the most common ones:

- Isolated - optotcoupler or relay
- Digital - A logic output, or over PMBus (or any available communication protocol)
- Optical - LED only

Electrically, the easiest way is to use a comparator and drive something with its output. But it can be tricked quite easily whilst the PSU is off by applying a voltage from an external source to the output terminals directly, so a false/fake DC_OK can be obtained, depending on the design of course.

One of the most reliable ways is to generate signal with a combination of AC_OK. AC_OK should be generated when there's proper input *(the input can be AC or DC depending on the application; but AC_OK is a traditional name)*, then DC_OK should be generated if there's AC_OK.

Here's a simplified diagram of an approach that I used in one of my designs before:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f89NX5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output of AC_OK (from the emitter of the left-most optocoupler) is used as a supply for DC_OK. So if there's no AC_OK then no DC_OK can be obtained.